# Why numpy transcendentals give "no attribute" error for integer arguments larger than 2^64-1?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Curiously, `np.log(2**64-1)` returns the float 44.3614196

but `np.log(2**64)` returns

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'log'
```

**Questions:**

- Why does numpy balk at arguments larger than 2^64-1?
- Why is the error `AttributeError` rather than a complaint about the size of the argument?

fyi: same benavior for other numpy transcendental functions (`sqrt`, `log10`, `cos`...)

Comment: Look at `np.array(2**64)`.  It's probably object dtype.  You are using Py2, right?

Comment: Incidentally, it looks like you mixed up some Python 2 and Python 3 behavior in your post. On any setup where `2**31` is a `long`, the `AttributeError` from `np.log(2**64)` should have said `'long'` instead of `'int'`.

Comment: @user2357112 Yes I was testing it in both and may have done that, I've converted question to Py3 only.

Comment: @hpaulj ditto..

Comment: `math` and `mpmath` will handle the larger integers - but not `numpy` arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NumPy has no native integer dtype large enough to hold `2**64`, so it gets `object` dtype handling. `object` dtype handling for `numpy.log` is to look for a `log` method on the object and call it, which is where the `AttributeError` comes from.

Comment: I see, thanks! Are there any cases where a numpy transcendental function is ever going to find a method on a natural numeric object?  Much of this is new to me, I'm trying to understand as much as I can from this.

Comment: @uhoh: Depends on what functions and what "natural" numeric objects you're considering. For example, `decimal.Decimal` objects support a few methods like `exp` and `log10`, which `numpy.exp` and `numpy.log10` will look for.

Comment: I've just adjusted the question to get rid of Py2 "contamination" but I don't think it affects your answer.